# I need to append an array of objects in a field of an object in a Postgres JSONB column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, go, jsonb

Note: I have not much experience with SQL.

I have a table `darf` which has two columns `uid` and `forms`

The `forms` column is a postgres jsonb type. I will store in the `uid` a name/email string and in the `forms` column I am storing a go struct as a JSONB type

```
type Forms struct {
  External []FormExternal
  Internal []FormInternal
  Download []FormDownloadPurchaseBU
  Purchase []FormDownloadPurchaseBU
  BU       []FormDownloadPurchaseBU
}
```

utilizing this function

```
func (f Forms) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(f)
}
```

I insert my first row using a query like this

```
func (db DB) InitialInsertQuery(email string, forms form.Forms) {
  initInsertQuery := "INSERT INTO darf (uid,forms) VALUES ($1, $2)"
  _ , err := db.Conn.Exec(initInsertQuery, email, forms)
}
```

I now have an entry in my table, and I want to add an object/struct to one of the Arrays[] in the
`forms` column object
`{"External": null, "Internal": null, "Download": [{...}], "Internal": null, "BU":       null, "Purchase": null, }`

First of all, when I initialize a new user I don't want those other fields to be null...How would I change that?

And secondly my main question is how do I append "Download" or any arrays in the jsonb `forms` column object fields?  I'm obviously trying to do this in Go.  But I have PG Admin4 up just trying to understand the SQL query itself first to even do such a thing.  I've found something along the lines of this

```
UPDATE darf SET darf.forms.Download = darf.forms.Download || '{...}' ::jsonb WHERE uid='useremail'
```

or I've also run into something jsonb_set(\something)
However I will also want it to be in Go and try and pass a form to add to one of the arrays in the jsonb object.

I'm ultimately trying to do something like this

```
func (db DB) InsertOneFormQuery(email string, form form.FormDownloadPurchaseBU) {
  initInsertQuery := "UPDATE darf APPEND darf.forms.Download VALUES ($1) WHERE uid=$2"
  _ , err := db.Conn.Exec(initInsertQuery, form, email)
}
```

Any insight would be amazing or even documentation or links.

Comment: Try `UPDATE darf SET forms = jsonb_insert(forms, '{Download,-1}', $1::jsonb, true) WHERE uid=$2`.

Comment: @mkopriva yes! worked so well! thank you!!